# returning 2 different values

Tags: java, return

i'm working with java in eclipse.I am trying to take 2 variables from my database and write it to an excel.My only problem is returning 2 different values(an integer and a string) from db reader method and send it to excel writer method which are in different classes.
Here is my db reader class:

```
public class DbConnection {
public void createConnection(String choice) {
    try {
        String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String db = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/digiturkschema";
        Class.forName(myDriver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db, "root",
                "*****");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        switch (choice) {
        case "write":
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM channelstable");
            while (rs.next()) {
                int channelId = rs.getInt("channelNo");
                String channelName = rs.getString("channelName");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        System.out.print(exception.getStackTrace());
    }
}
}
```

I need to return "channelId" and "channelName" from this method to this method:

```
public class WritingToExcel {
public void Write() throws IOException {
    try {
        JFileChooser f = new JFileChooser();
        f.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        f.showSaveDialog(null);

        System.out.println(f.getCurrentDirectory());
        System.out.println(f.getSelectedFile());
        String direction = f.getSelectedFile().toString() + "\\DigiTurkKanalListesi.xls";

        WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(direction));
        WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Kanal Listesi", 0);

        Label label = new Label(0, 0, "A label record");
        sheet.addCell(label);

        Number number = new Number(2, 1, 3.1459);
        sheet.addCell(number);

        workbook.write();
        workbook.close();
    } catch (WriteException e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

I know that writingToExcel class is not completed and it's ok,i can finish it if i can take these two variables to this class.By the way i am using MVC pattern so i have a controller class between them.I can write it too if it's necessary.

Comment: Is `channelId` always unique? If so, you can store them in a `Map<Integer, String>` and pass that.

Comment: yeah it's unique and pk of the table.I will search for using Map<>.Thank you for your idea :)

Comment: If order doesn't matter, use `HashMap`. If order does matter, use `LinkedHashMap`. Map is a key-value pairing. So your key would be the channeld and the value would be channelName.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ascalonian said, you can use [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) or [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

for example:

```
Map<Integer, String> channelInfo = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

You can also (but should not):

Create a new class with the values you need and return that class. (You will be doing extra work which you don't really need to.)

Create setter methods for those variables and use it before calling the method to write to excel. (requires caution as you can end up with undesired values if you mess the code)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options

- `ArrayList<Objects>` : During Iterating the **resultSet** prepare temporary List say **tempList** insert items into **tempList** and then after each iteration add **tempList** to **Main List** , Since **ArrayList** is a sequential list. So, insertion and retrieval order is the same. So you can return this from your **dbReader()** method .Then use them wherever you want

**Your Arraylist will look like this**

```
[ [1,Channel 1] , [2,Channel 2] , [3,Channel 3] ]
```

- `Map` if order is important prefer `LinkedHashMap` if order is not your primary concern then opt for `HashMap`